# Ejecutar PHP con cron

Tags: php, centos, crontab, cron, yii

Necesito ejecutar un script de PHP automáticamente, y para ello estoy usando el Cron de Cent'os y el proyecto está escrito con el framework Yii. El caso es que estoy intentando añadir un crontab con:

```
crontab -e
```

Y depués añado la ruta del script y el momento en el que quiero que se ejecute:

```
***** /var/www/html/ClubGolf cliente/informeMateriales
```

(El proyecyo es `ClubGolf`, el controlador es `cliente` e `informeMateriales` es una acción del controlador)

Cuando ejecuto el crontab me sale un error diciéndome que está mal puesta la hora (o algo así) y no sé porqué puede suceder:

```
"/tmp/crontab.wqcMnf":1: bad hour errors in crontab file, can't install
```

A lo mejor he escrito mal el crontab, o también puede ser que haya escrito mal la ruta, ya que no escribo una ruta completa, sino que le llevo directamente a la acción del controlador...

Comment: Prueba con espacios entre los valores de la hora. Aparte no se si se puede poner todo *

Answer (score 1):

Al ser un archivo php necesitas que este se ejecute con el interprete de php.

En la terminal se utiliza para ejecutar archivos php `php file.php`. 
Para llamar funciones de un archivo PHP en la linea de comandos, se utiliza `php -r`, que esto lo que hace es ejecutar lo que tiene entre comillas. entonces,  primero, incluimos el fichero donde esta la funcion y luego llamamos a la funcion que quieres ejecutar.
Por lo que en el crontab deberia ejecutarlo tal y como la consola.

Creo que lo mejor es que hagas un archivo .sh con la ejecucion del crontab:

file.cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
php -r "require '/path/to/file.php'; functionToExecute()"
```

Y luego en el crontab:

```
* * * * * username /path/to/file.cron.sh
```

Comment: Hola buenas! Lo siento por contestar tan tarde! Acabo de probar lo que me acabas de decir y no me funciona. ¿No hay alguna otra manera para llamar a una funcion de php?

Comment: Como lo has hecho? puedes poner el codigo del archivo .sh?

Comment: `php -r "require '/var/www/html/ClubGolf/clubdegolf/protected/modules/cliente/controllers/ClienteController.php'; actionInformeMateriales();`"

Comment: y el `actionInformeMateriales()` esta dentro de alguna clase?
Si el codigo es correcto, si ejecutas `sh file.sh` sale algun error?

Comment: Está dentro de un Controlador, ClienteController.php

Comment: Los controladores de yii son como clases por lo que la funcion es un metodo.  Tendras que instanciar la clase, y luego llamar a la funcion. A ver si te funciona algo como esto: 
`$obj =new ClienteController(); $obj->actionInformeMateriales(); exit();`

Lo que no se muy bien es que necesitas de Yii, por lo que a lo mejor necesitas que Yii se ejecute tambien.

Comment: Me pone este errror: `Cannot redeclare class Yii in line 28` y no hay nada en esa línea, es la clase Yii que extiende de YiiBase y no contiene nada.

Comment: He estado leyendo sobre Yii, y he encontrado esto: [ejecutar funcion desde la vista](https://yatinmistry.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/yii-framework-call-controller-function-from-view/), Entonces la funcion debe ser publica y llamarla de manera `ClienteController::actionInformeMateriales()`

Comment: Entonces el archivo .sh qué contendrá? El require y lo que me acabas de decir?

Comment: Es que yo no puedo probarlo, por que no tendria que intalarme Yii, pero deberia ser tal `php -r "include_once '/var/www/html/ClubGolf/clubdegolf/protected/modules/cliente/controllers/ClienteController.php'; 
ClienteController::actionInformeMateriales();"`

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear un comando dentro de `Yii` y llamarlo a través de la terminal y del interprete de `PHP`

En la propia documentación de `Yii` tienes como crear un comando de consola, que simplemente podría llamar a esa función: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console#create-command

Una vez tengas ese comando y se ejecute bien directamente en la termina puedes ponerlo en el cron de la siguiente manera:

`***** /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/yii mi-comando`

Lo primero es el interprete de PHP, lo segunda la ruta a tu `Yii` y lo tercero el nombre del comando dentro de `Yii`

Recuerda modificar el cron del usuario que tiene permisos en la carpeta por si tiene que crear algún fichero o algo te lo cree con ese usuario y no otro o te de un error.

Si tienes dudas me comentas.